# PHP file not call using $.post (JQuery version I should used?)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Test.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.post('MYLogic.php', null, function(response) {
   });
});
```

Can any one tell me which jQuery or version of JQuery should I include on my JSP page to call PHP class using $.post

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <link type="text/css" href="css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link type="text/css" href="css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link type="text/css" href="css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/test.js"></script>
    <title>Mobilezone Afghanistan</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Any version. `$.post()` has been part of jQuery since v1.

Comment: check your browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: i don't think you need that null parameter, you can pass the callback as the second parameter if you have no data to send

Comment: @andrew You are correct ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
Remove `null`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.post('MYLogic.php', function(response) {
   });
});
```